# get values from one xml and match them with other xml nodes based on condition

Tags: xslt

For example consider xml1 as:

```
     <hexam>
      <exam>
        <weightage>2</weightage>
        <examid>1</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>kiwi</opt1>
            <opt2>lemon</opt2>
        </responseoption>
        <selectedoption>
        </selectedoption>
      </exam>
      <exam>
        <weightage>3</weightage>
        <examid>2</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>apple</opt1>
            <opt2>orange</opt2>
        </responseoption>
        <selectedoption>
        </selectedoption>
      </exam>
     </hexam>
```

Consider a xml2 as:

```
    <hexam>
     <exam>
      <weightage>
      </weightage>
      <examid>1</examid>
      <responseoption>
      </responseoption>
      <selectedoption>
        <opt2>lemon</opt2>
      </selectedoption>
     </exam>
    </hexam>
```

Now this is how my output has to look like after processing xsl:

```
     <hexam>
      <exam>
        <weightage>2</weightage>
        <examid>1</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>kiwi</opt1>
            <opt2>lemon</opt2>
        </responseoption>
      <selectedoption>
        <opt2>lemon</opt2>
      </selectedoption>
      </exam>
      <exam>
        <weightage>3</weightage>
        <examid>2</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>apple</opt1>
            <opt2>orange</opt2>
        </responseoption>
        <selectedoption>
        </selectedoption>
      </exam>
     </hexam>
```

My XSLT coding is based on second xml(xml2), So my output xml should fetch weightage,examid,responseoption from xml1 along with selected option from xml2.If examid is not available in xml2 on comparing with xml1, then whole child nodes of exam corresponding to that examid has to be processed from xml1. Please help me here. Refer my output xml.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (last two lines).

Comment: Please show your XSLT attempt. Also, the question is not clear - what "condition" are you trying to test for?

Comment: I m trying to test based on exam id.. Whenever examid matches,the blank fields of xml2 like weightage,response option has to be filled.If examid does not match then  it has to be retrieved as such from xml1. In my case examid=1 matches, then the blank nodes like weightage,responseoption of xml2 , their values has to be filled(refer output xml). Since my examid=2 is not present in xml1, then this to be displayed as such(refer output xml)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared input XMLs, it looks like `xml1` is the XML containing the questions and the `xml2` is the one corresponding to the responses for the questions from `xml1`.

From the structure of the output, the easier option is to merge `<selectedoption>` element from `xml2` into the structure of `xml1` for the matching `<examid>`, but since your requirement is to apply the XSLT on `xml2` you can try out the below solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:param name="xml1" select="document('xml1.xml')/hexam"/>

    <xsl:template match="hexam">
        <hexam>
            <xsl:for-each select="exam">
                <xsl:variable name="examid2" select="examid" />
                <xsl:variable name="selectedoption2" select="selectedoption" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$xml1/exam">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$examid2 = examid">
                            <exam>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="weightage | examid | responseoption" />
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$selectedoption2" />
                            </exam>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </hexam>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<hexam>
    <exam>
        <weightage>2</weightage>
        <examid>1</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>kiwi</opt1>
            <opt2>lemon</opt2>
        </responseoption>
        <selectedoption>
            <opt2>lemon</opt2>
        </selectedoption>
    </exam>
    <exam>
        <weightage>3</weightage>
        <examid>2</examid>
        <responseoption>
            <opt1>apple</opt1>
            <opt2>orange</opt2>
        </responseoption>
        <selectedoption />
    </exam>
</hexam>
```

Comment: You might to slightly amend the answer because strictly speaking it is an error to use a variable reference in a template match in XSLT 1.0 (although some processors do allow it). Alternatively, use XSLT 2.0 :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my xslt is appied on xml2. I need to retrieve   all other nodes along with selected option whenever exam id matches from xml1. Please help on the same.

Comment: The solution has been updated so that it can be applied on `xml2` and references `xml1`.